# Maven - process-class phase - How to copy only changed classes?

Tags: java, maven

When building one of our jars, we have something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
        <mainClass>someone.elses.closedsource.ClassFileModifier</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <argument>...</argument>
            <argument>someone.elses.closedsource.ClassFileModifier</argument>
            <argument>-config</argument>
            <argument>...</argument>
            <argument>-in</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
            <argument>-out</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In short, after the code is compiled, the *ClassFileModifier* goes over all classes, does some voodoo magic on them, and overwrites the compiled classes, with the modified classes.

How could I change our build, so that it still runs on all classes, as I'm not sure if a change in one class, would cause the dependent class to also need to be changed, but then detect if anything changed in the modified classes since the last build, and only have classes copied to ${project.build.outputDirectory} if there is an actual change?

I suspect I would have to have the originally compiled classes saved somewhere else then ${project.build.outputDirectory}, and have the modified classes saved somewhere else again, and have somehow the modified classes compared to the classes in ${project.build.outputDirectory}, and only copied in ${project.build.outputDirectory} if missing or different, and ideally superfluous classes in ${project.build.outputDirectory}, that are missing in the modified class directory, be deleted.

The purpose of this desired change, is that there is a lot of stuff that depends on this jar (this is a 2.5M LOC codebase), and the dependent sub-projects should only be recompiled, if there really was a change here.

Comment: This is a job for maven plugin not for exec maven plugin...so get your stuff into a maven plugin than you can much more...

Comment: @khmarbaise Just to be sure I understand you: you mean that I need to write my own Maven plugin, to do what I asked for?